# Regex to check URL domain ended with forwad slash

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I am really new to regex. I try to search and also try some similar solution in every stackoverflow but no luck to find the solution that I really need. I need help to check the URL that needs contain at least one forward slash ('/') in addition to the protocol part (e.g. 'https://') of the url. Meaning it needs to be a forward slash after the domain part of the URL prefix.

for example:

- https://someurl.com/ <- valid
- http://www.url.gg/ <- valid
- http://sample.com/some-api/edit <- valid
- https://test <- not valid
- https://www.test.com <- not valid

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match an additional slash after the protocol and a wild card:

```
^https?://.*/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/9KGMGO/1

Comment: This will match `https://test/` as well. Better should be `^https?://.*\..*/`

Comment: Nowhere in the question does the OP say `https://test/` is an invalid case. `https://test/` is also a valid URL elsewhere as `test` would refer to a local server named `test`.

Comment: The question is clearly about domain validation and as per `https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034`, `test` is NOT a valid domain.

Comment: That is *your* interpretation. The only one thing that is "clear" in the question is that the OP wants to test if the URL contains a `/` in the path. Everything else is inferred. The fact that `https://test` is one of the sample test cases in the OP's question means to me that the OP recognizes `test` as a valid host, but just needs a slash to make it valid per the OP's requirement.

Comment: Also, RFC-1034 is about the definition of a *domain name* while the question is specially about *URL* validation with a special requirement that the path portion needs to contain a slash. Big difference there.

Comment: thank you. it helps me resolve. yes as advay mention, it also require a domain check. but I manage to resolve domain issue. thank you all